# How to list files in S3 using a wildcard in the path

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, shell, unix, amazon-s3

I need to do an `ls` in a dynamic directory on AWS S3. I have part of the name, and the rest is dynamic, example:

```
aws s3 ls s3://mybuckt/14102020/myfiles.csv
```

The fixed field I have is year month, the day that is always dynamic, each month comes on a different day.

I tried to use:

```
aws s3 ls s3://mybuckt/*102020/myfiles.csv
```

I tried using the `*` wildcard but it didn't work, does anyone have any idea how to do it?

Comment: AWS's ListObject API doesn't support searches.  From the command line, you'll need to do something like `aws s3 ls s3://mybucket --recursive | grep 102020/myfiles.csv` to search keys for some value.

Comment: @AnonCoward, With the ls command it works, but when I go to cp it doesn't have the same behavior, do you have any idea how to make the cp command work in this case?

Comment: You can use `--exclude "*" --include "*12020/myfiles.csv"` in the cp command to control the selection of files.

Comment: @AnonCoward, would be like this? aws s3 cp {root_folder} {temp_folder} | --exclude "*" --include "*102021/"'

Comment: See: [AWS CLI: Use of Exclude and Include Filters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you pipe the output into `grep` like this:

```bash
aws s3 ls s3://mybuckt/* --recursive | grep "102020/myfiles.csv"
```